# Issue with Importing CSV File into WEKA

Tags: csv, import, weka

I am getting the following error when I try to import a CSV file into WEKA:
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cweHa.png)]
wrong number of values. Read 284, expected 35, read Token[EOL], line 2 Problem encountered on line:2.

WEKA Version 3.8.6 if it helps.

I have tried to remove all - / , symbols.

I cannot figure out which cell is the problem.

Please assist :)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! had ' and " in other fields/cells :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).